# Skype4Py Getting a message

Tags: python, python-2.7, skype4py

So, I'm working on making my own skype bot for my group, but I can not figure out how to retrieve the latest message for my life. I quickly consulted the internet and stackoverflow as I am oft to do with little issues, but there is almost non-existent documentation for specific functions in the Skype4Py documentation, and nothing here on stackoverflow. Here's my code, and help please?

```
#Importing!
import time, sys
import Skype4Py

#Set skypeclient and connect, while also setting my desired user
skypeClient = Skype4Py.Skype()
skypeClient.Attach()
user = sys.argv[1]

#Loop!
while 1:
    """
    Here I am stumped. I have tried skypeClient.Chat.GetRecentMessages(),
    skypeClient.Chat.Chat.GetRecentMessages
    and that wouldn't even work for my purposes if it did work!
    """
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
def Commands(Message, Status):
    if Status == 'SENT' or (Status == 'RECEIVED'):
        running = 1
        message = Message.Body.lower()
        handle = Message.FromHandle.upper()
        if running == 1:
            if message == 'WHATEVER':
```

Then later on,

```
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
skype.OnMessageStatus = Commands
skype.Attach()
while True:
    pass
```

Worked for me!